# How do I refer "this" keyword to another function on callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, call

I am trying to create a reference on the callback function of the click method. I would like `this` to refer to the `href` that was clicked. How should I go about doing that? I have read about using the `.call` method but it is not 100% clear to me..

Below is my code snippet which I am working on. I have left a comment where I am experiencing the trouble.

```
var scrollTo = {
    init: function(config) {
        var href = config.element;

        href.on('click', this.scroll);

    },

    scroll: function(e) {
        var target = this.attr('href'), // I would like "this" to refer to the href.onClick element
            sT = $(target).offset().top;

            console.log(this);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: sT
            }, 2000);

            e.preventDefault();

    }

}

scrollTo.init({
    element: $('a[href^="#"]')
});
```

Comment: `this` points to the element which fired the event.... which object do you want it to point to

Comment: I would like `this` to point to the href element which is clicked (you can find it in the init function)

Comment: it is pointing to that element

Comment: Right! my mistake. I just needed to write `$(this).attr` instead of `this.attr`. Thanks for the help, 4 min until I can hit the green check mark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` because in the callback function `this` points to the dom element not to the jQuery wrapped element thus it does not have the method `.attr()`

```
var target = $(this).attr('href')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ayye9/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, maybe using the [jQuery.proxy() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) can help?  It makes a new function reference from an existing one and redefines what "this" (the context) is in the called function.